# Oracle query to select first 3 characters after every underscore

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to write oracle sql query to select only first 3 characters from a string after every underscore character.

For example:

`'oracle_mydatabase_table'` - original string,

`'ora_myd_tab'`             - required output.

Can anybody help me to write sql query or pl/sql procedure to do this?

Comment: You will have to give it your best try first.

Comment: Nah, just wait around -- based on experience, someone will give you the code for the 15 points. Of course then you won't have learned the method for finding new knowledge yourself.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - Yes, OP is lazy.  But his problem is interesting enough.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - I consider answering questions like this to be beneficial. By having the answer supplied rather than learning how to do it on his/her/its own OP doesn't learn anything other than how to be a parrot.  By not learning, OP fails course. By failing course, OP doesn't become my co-worker. So, beneficial...

Answer (score 4):

```
regexp_replace(your_string, '((^|_)[^_]{1,3})[^_]*', '\1')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it is working fine for me as expected. :)